# Запись данных в файл .json

Tags: c#, json

У меня есть класс, с помощью которого я хочу сохранить два списка в один файл, для дальнейшей работы с ним.

Классы списки которых мне нужны:

```
public class Person
    {
        public int PersonalIdentificator { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DeathDate { get; set; }
        public List<int> IdParents { get; set; }
    }
public class GridsInformation
    {
        public (int, int) SourceCoordinates { get; set; }
    }
```

Сама модель:

```
private class SavingModel
        {
            public SavingModel(List<Person> people, List<GridsInformation> information)
            {
                Person = people;
                Information = information;
            }

            List<Person> Person;
            List<GridsInformation> Information;

        }
```

И метод, который записывает в файл:

```
public static void WriteInfoFileJson(string path, List<Person> people, List<GridConnectionInfo> information, Grid choosedGrid)
        {
            List<GridsInformation> coordinatesSource = GetCoordinates(information, choosedGrid);
            SavingModel saving = new(people, coordinatesSource);
            
            string reading = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(saving); 
            File.WriteAllText(path, reading);
        }
```

По отладке посмотрел, сами списки записываются не пустые, но в файле при записи вижу только `{}`

Comment: сериализация/десериализация работает с публичными объектами, некоторые сериализаторы еще и требуют свойства. Так что `List<Person> Person;` -> `public List<Person> Person {get; set;}`, либо помечайте атрибутом (опять же, зависит от сериализатора).

Comment: Даже и не подумал сделать свойствами, а оказывается все довольно просто. Спасибо большое!

Comment: `public` добавьте